# How to get the name of component at which stepfunction has failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions, jmespath

I have list of `executionArn` of `stepfunction` execution, I am filtering those `executionArn` by `status == 'FAILED'`.

Now, how can I get the exact failure of the `stepfunction` in Python, (meaning: at which point the execution has failed)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
import boto3
import jmespath

client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')


full_result = (
    client
    .get_paginator('get_execution_history')
    .paginate(arn=<your arn>)
    .build_full_result()
)

exn_failed_event = jmespath.search('events[?type==`ExecutionFailed`]', full_result)
```

The `exn_failed_event` dictionary will look something like this

```py
[
  {
    'executionFailedEventDetails': {
         'cause': 
           'An error occurred while executing '
           "the state 'Lambda Invoke' (entered "
           'at the event id #4). Invalid path '
           "'$.foo' : No results for path: "
           "$['foo']",
         'error': 'States.Runtime'
    },
    'id': 11,
    'previousEventId': 0,
    'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 11, 19, 0, 24, 2000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'type': 'ExecutionFailed'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this issue in `boto3` repository](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/949), it looks like there is a `search` method that you can call on an iterator object.

So your actual code could be simplified — and gather less unneeded data — to:

```py
import boto3

failed_events = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
  .get_paginator('get_execution_history')
  .paginate(arn=<your arn>)
  .search('events[?type==`ExecutionFailed`]')
```

Comment: Would you not still need to execute an additional query get the details of the event that actually failed? Also, some additional context wrt to "and gather less unneeded data", filtering is done client side meaning he same amount of data is getting returned from the API, only the resulting object the response is saved to is 'smaller'